# How to calculate corner(edge) coordinates for geo image

Tags: georeferencing

I want to add image layer to Azure map. To do that I need coordinates for the corners. With help of this site http://viglino.github.io/Map-georeferencer  I am able to get center, rotation/angle and scale but having trouble to calculate coordiates for the corners. To calclate coordinates I tried:

```
TOP RIGHT :
Top_Right.x = center.x + ((width / 2) *(scale.x) * cos(angle)) - ((height / 2) *(scale.y) * sin(angle))
Top_Right.y = center.y + ((width / 2) *(scale.x) * sin(angle)) + ((height / 2) *(scale.y) * cos(angle))


TOP LEFT :
Top_Left.x = center.x - ((width / 2) *(scale.x) * cos(angle)) - ((height / 2) *(scale.y) * sin(angle))
Top_Left.y = center.y - ((width / 2) *(scale.x) * sin(angle)) + ((height / 2) *(scale.y) * cos(angle))


BOTTOM LEFT :
Bot_Left.x = center.x - ((width / 2) *(scale.x) * cos(angle)) + ((height / 2) *(scale.y) * sin(angle))
Bot_Left.y = center.y - ((width / 2) *(scale.x) * sin(angle)) - ((height / 2) *(scale.y) * cos(angle))


BOTTOM RIGHT:
Bot_Right.x = center.x + ((width / 2) *(scale.x) * cos(angle)) + ((height / 2) *(scale.y) * sin(angle))
Bot_Right.y = center.y + ((width / 2) *(scale.x) * sin(angle)) - ((height / 2) *(scale.y) * cos(angle))
```

But output is incorrect.

Comment: in what way is the answer incorrect? please give the values you are using and what you expect the answer to be